# JIRA plugins wont load after Virtual Machine suspension

Tags: virtual-machine, jira

Currently, I've got JIRA 6.3.4 on a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine. The machine wasn't accessed over a period of time and was suspended, shutting down JIRA. After re-enabling the VM, JIRA fails to start. The logs indicate that 29 plugins failed to load due to time out errors. There is also an issue when running stop_service.bat; the console states that the service is stopping, then the service could not be stopped, but checking the services tab of Task Manager shows the service not to be running. the logs then show an error:

```
2014-09-29 11:01:26,978 Timer-2 ERROR      [atlassian.event.internal.AsynchronousAbleEventDispatcher] There was an exception thrown trying to dispatch event
'[com.atlassian.plugin.event.events.PluginModuleUnavailableEvent@ad1f36, 
SingleParameterMethodListenerInvoker{method=public void com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.onPluginModuleUnavailable(com.atlassian.plugin.event.events.PluginModuleUnavailableEvent),
 listener=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.JiraPluginManager@53c871}]' from the invoker 'java.lang.RuntimeException: service proxy has been destroyed'
```

I have tried increasing the plugin timeout parameter to 300 seconds but this doesn't seem to have had any effect. I've also increased the the amount of memory allocated to JIRA and deleted some of the plugins subfolders in case of a corrupted plugin cache, but this hasn't changed anything either.

Also present in the logs is an error stating that the org.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER system property is not set to true, when in reality it has bee nset to true in the setenv.bat file, so could these be related?

Would there be any other workarounds or solutions, or am I looking at a re-installation?

EDIT: I've also tried increasing the MaxPermGen memory to 384Mb in the event that its a lack of memory causing the issues but, again, this has had no effect, neither has adding the JIRA directory to the exceptions section of the antivirus installed on the VM. Also, the current JDK and JRE versions being used are 7, as well as apache Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem and our problem seemed to be that our java paths (JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME) contained white-spaces. We moved our javainstallation directly unto C:\ and changed both paths and then ran

```
service.bat remove
service.bat install
```

Some of the information was available in the following confluence page:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/JIRA+Service+Fails+To+Start+in+Windows+-+Is+Not+a+Valid+Win32+Application

It worked for us!